# return statement in macro(#define) in C

Tags: c

Is it possible to write a macro for the following function:

```
char *sent_same_text(char *txt)
{
    return txt;
}
```

I tried

```
#define sent_same_text(txt) return(txt);
```

but getting compilation error.

Comment: Umm... `#define sent_same_txt(txt) (txt)`? But why would you want to do that?

Comment: Am writing this for future use(will do some string manipulation).

Comment: Maybe you are misunderstanding the uses of macros? Why do you feel a macro will be appropriate for what you want to implement? My gut feeling is that you will want a (possibly inline) function and that a macro is the wrong tool, but only you can answer that.

Comment: Also, never put a `;` as a terminator inside the macro itself.

Answer (score 6):

Simply do:

```
#define sent_same_text(txt) (txt)
```

You only need `return` for functions. A macro is different in that it is a literal string insertion into your code. Make sure you have the parentheses around txt.

Answer (score 3):

A return statement in a macro will return from the function that "calls" the macro.  Function-like macros are shorthand for generating the same code multiple times.  They are not actual function calls.

Here's an example of why you might put a return in a macro:

```
/* do-while() loop is a trick to let you define multi-statement macros and */
/* call them like functions. Note the lack of trailing ';' */
#define ERROR(msg) do{ fprintf(stderr, (msg)); errorCount++; return -1; }while(0)

/* foo() returns 0 or success or -1 on failure */
int foo(int x, int y){
   if ( x < 10 )
   {
      ERROR("x is out of range\n");
   }
   if ( y < 20 )
   {
      ERROR("y is out of range\n");
   }
   doSomething(x,y);
   return 0;
}
```

Calling foo with x = 25 would result in a return of -1, and the message "x is out of range" being printed.

Not saying that is good style, but hopefully illustrates how a return in a macro is different from a return in a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define sent_same_text(text) (text)
```

Comment: You really should have parentheses around text.

Comment: What quasiverse says. Otherwise, your macro version of `sent_same_text` produces a different result in the expression `*sent_same_text(something+1)` from what the function version would produce. The macro makes that expression equivalent to `(*something)+1`, the function makes it equivalent to `*(something+1)`. To the extent anyone would want to use this macro at all, `(*something)+1` likely isn't what they want.